# How could Thanos bleed red during a fight with Iron Man? Color of his blood is purple

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

**Incident 1:**
During Gamora's fight with Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War* the color of Thanos' blood was purple.

[image]

**Incident 2:**
Tony Stark made Thanos bleed. "All of this for a drop o' blood." This time the color of Thanos' blood was red.

[image]

**Incident 3:**
Thor shoved stormbreaker into Thanos' chest. This time the color of Thanos' blood was purple.

[image]

**Why was it red when Thanos was fighting with Tony Stark?**

Comment: I found these on the internet, wasn't much info available. Still these are not good for posting answers. Found these from quora, **1.** *Maybe it's related to how the pigments of thanos's blood reacting to the light in the earth's atmosphere in comparison to the the light's refraction on the titan.*

**2.** *Or it can be as simple as some technical error in the post filming effects leading to this inconsistency in the color of thanos's blood in two different scenes.*

Comment: I was also thinking same. That it's the atmospheric effect which is different on earth and Titan, but Knowhere, there also it was purple. So seems it is Marvel's mistake they should pay me for catching this bug.

Comment: At Knowwhere, it wasn't a true incident, it was an illusion intended for Gamora. How Gamora knows Thanos, What Gamora expects from Thanos, that's what it is...

Comment: I don't think so. If it was Gamora's thinking then why everyone else were also seeing same. So it was Thanos' thinking, the way he wanted them to see the things, he projected that. Hence, per Thanos his blood is purple, not red.

Comment: I can't see the blood is red....it sure looks purple to me. This is a lighting issue I think.

Comment: I would define the blood in all three pictures as more or less **grape** colored.

Comment: @Flater Yeah, color on fingers is punctured grape (juice) and others are outer skin of grape. :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid you are mistaken.

Clearly the blood on Thanos' fingers is **purple**...this would be consistent with how it appears in the rest of the movie.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Two things. They messed up and it isn’t really important. Or the light was reflecting on it in a way that caused it to appear a different color then what was expected.

Comment: Just one liner - Russo brothers don't mess up.